Does recursive call have to be strictly the last call in a function for a function to be tail-recursive?
Inspired by a post on Reddit (someone wanted to count frequencies in commonlisp forum), I wanted to write a list-based one for the fun and practice, hash-based one is of course more efficient. I got this one first:
    (defun count-frequences (list)
      (let* ((len (length list))
             (elt (car list))
             (lst (delete elt list)))
        (if (null lst)
            (cons (cons elt (- len (length lst))) nil)
            (cons (cons elt (- len (length lst)))
                  (count-frequences lst)))))

I thought it wasn't tail-recursive, since it calls itself  through a call to another function, so I re-wrote it like this:
    (defun count-frequences (list &optional freq)
      (let* ((len (length list))
             (elt (car list))
             (lst (delete elt list)))
        (push (cons elt (- len (length lst))) freq)
        (if (null lst)
            freq
            (count-frequences lst freq))))

However, when I look at the generated assembly code in SBCL, both seem to be optimized, with recursive function calls removed and replaced with loops, when compiled with optimizations. The produced assembly is not the same, and the first one is somewhat longer.
So what is going on? Just SBCL performing optimization even if a function is not tail-recursive, or are both tail recursive?
Does call to itself have to be strictly the last statement in the function for a function to be tail recursive?

afaik SBCL can optimize non-tail-recursive functions in some cases (tail recursion modulo cons), but writing tail-recursive code often leads to clearer and more predictable optimizations

Thanks. So the first one indeed is not tail recursive. The compiler just performed something similar to TCO anyway? I think also that the second one is a bit cleaner, and even the produced assembly seems more effective.

("frequences" isn't quite the same as frequencies. And isn't it count occurrences, build a histogram, or establish frequencies? "count frequencies" seems to yield the same as count distinct values.)

Correct, it's not tail-recursive. The compiler is probably performing common sub-expression elimination, because it sees the expression (cons elt (- len (length lst))) in both branches of the if. This then allows it to transform into code similar to the tail recursive version.

TRMC optimization is probably / likely at play here.

Thanks @Barmar and Will Ness, I wasn't familiar with TRMC optimization, but that explains it. And that optimization does make sense, since the code is almost tail recursive. Learned something :-).

@greybeard Sorry if my English is bad; it is my third language. Yes, that number of occurences of a value in a list, whichever word you want to use. And if it matters, I have used destructive operations, so you perhaps would prefer to call it ncount-occurencies, to emphasize the danger of modifying the list. I personally don't think it should be used for anything, so the wording does not matter. It was just a curious exercise in Lisp programming.

Following @Barmar's comment, the first step might look like this -
(defun count-frequences (list)
  (let* ((len (length list))
         (elt (car list))
         (lst (delete elt list))
         (val (cons elt (- len (length lst))))) ;; refactor
    (if (null lst)
        (cons val nil)
        (cons val (count-frequences lst))))) ;; trmc

Which can be further optimized to using tail recursion modulo cons (trmc).
